# Angular-material mat-table *matRowDef dynamically generated with *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a mat-table with several fields and at least two content types. I switch fields on and off according to the current content type. This works fine.

What I want to achieve now is to add *matRowDef dynamically, according to the same content type. I have some description and other fields which are going to the second or third line. I already have a `getContentDisplayedColumns()` method that gives back the columns for every row eg:

```
<tr mat-row 
  *matRowDef="let element; columns: getContentDisplayedColumns(2)" 
  class="description-row" 
  @rowsAnimation>
</tr>
```

This gives back the column names that should be displayed with the current content type and for row 2. So now I have to write one *matRowDefs for every row I want to show getting the columns displayed in that row. But I don't know how many "descriptor" rows I will have so this should work dynamically, for example (that is not working):

```
<tr mat-row 
  *ngFor="let rowNumber of getContentRows()" -- this 
  *matRowDef="let element; columns: getContentDisplayedColumns(rowNumber)" 
  class="description-row" 
  @rowsAnimation>
</tr>
```

getContentRows() gives a number array. It gives the error:

> Property 'rowNumber' does not exist on type

I'm using Angular and Angular material 13.2

I thought that it is declared in *ngFor.

**Update**

getContentDisplayedColumns method is just giving back string[] by a list.

```
getContentDisplayedColumns(row: number): string[] {
    if (this.draftGroup !== null && this.contentDataSource !== null && this.contentDataSource !== undefined && this.contentDataSource.data && this.contentDataSource.data.length > 0) {
      switch (this.draftGroup.get('DocType')?.value) {
        case DocumentTypes.dDocument_Items: return ColumnDescriptors.ItemColumns.filter(x => x.row === row).map(x => x.field);
        case DocumentTypes.dDocument_Service: return ColumnDescriptors.ServiceColumns.filter(x => x.row === row).map(x => x.field);

        default: return ColumnDescriptors.ItemColumns.filter(x => x.row === row).map(x => x.field);
      }
    } else {
      return ColumnDescriptors.ItemColumns.filter(x => x.row === row).map(x => x.field);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post getContentDisplayedColumns?

Comment: @Vega Updated post with the missing method, but I think it's irrelevant as it's just a string array. The question is **how can I use *ngFor to declare *matRowDef for mat-table?**